# WebDriverEventListener and loggin sendKeys data

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have been using `WebDriverEventListener` to log various message and one of them is the data used by sendKeys method. API -`org.openqa.selenium.support.events.WebDriverEventListener#beforeChangeValueOf` can be used to log messages before keying in data in text field. But I get access to only element locator using `WebElement` argument. Is there a way to also access data which is keyed in to element?

Answer (score 0):

Before change method you are providing element locator, so you get the value as you do for an input field. Implement the **beforeChangeValueOf** method as follows-

```
public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver arg1) {
   System.out.println("Before change: "+element.getAttribute("value"));  
}
```

Comment: why would the attribute value be the value of data to be entered in element? It is not even entered in the field

Answer (score 0):

Use the method:

```
public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element,
                               WebDriver driver,
                               java.lang.CharSequence[] keysToSend);
```

`keysToSend` parameter will give you the keyed data.